# ¿Cómo mostrar la primera opción del menú activa por default en Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código, lo que quiero hacer es que al entrar a la pagina, por default marque el primer menú activo y las otras dos opciones estén inhabilitadas.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active" id="0">
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">SERVICIOS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="active" id="1">
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">CLIENTES</a>
    </li>

    <li class="active" id="2">
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">CONTACTO</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Como le puedo hacer para resaltar  la primera opción del menú como activa y las otras dos inhabilitadas

Answer (score 0):

Y si haces esto :

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active" id="0">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">SERVICIOS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item disabled" id="1">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">CLIENTES</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item disabled" id="2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">CONTACTO</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```